# Xamarin.Forms StackLayout IsVisible not working on Android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.forms

I have the following problem: IsVisible binding is not working, stacklayout is still visible and i don't know how to do it the right way. I have added IsVisible to list and all list have disappeared. I would like that only StackLayout shows if item of list is selected. Of course, besides public new bool etc. I have the rest of code with InitializeComponent(); etc.

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage, ISwipeCallBack
{
    private bool _isVisible = false;
    public new bool IsVisible
    {
        get => _isVisible;
        set => Set(ref _isVisible, value);
    }

    private object Set(ref bool isVisible, bool value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

private void ChallengeList_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
      //  if (e.SelectedItem == null)
     //       return;
        if (e.SelectedItem is MainPage viewModel)
        {
            viewModel.IsVisible = true;
        }

     //   ChallengeList.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ChallengeList" SeparatorColor="#3d122c" HasUnevenRows="True"
            ItemSelected="ChallengeList_ItemSelected"  RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=Lab, Constant=0,Factor=1,Property=Height,Type=RelativeToView}"
      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Property=Height,Factor=0.8,Type=RelativeToParent}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  BackgroundColor="#40FFFFFF" Padding="10">
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#ff3f50" FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" x:Name="More" Padding="5">
                                    <Label Text="sdfghjkhgfdsfghjkljhgfdsadfghjkljhgfdsaSDFGHJKJHGFDSAsdfghjkhgfds" TextColor="#ff3f50" FontSize="17" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

Comment: ...what about that NotImplementedException there on the Set method?

Comment: I made a basic demo with your posted codes, but failed to reproduce the problem. Could you please post more detailed codes? or maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem through online repo.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT chat?

Comment: We are not in the same time zone. And it's better for other people to figure out what's going on through detailed posted codes or a basic demo shared through online repository.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I'm having the same issue here actually. I was able to work around the problem for now by toggling Opacity rather than IsVisible.

Comment: So, I had my content wrapped in a scroll view. When I remove the scroll view, everything works as expected.

Comment: May 2018 with Xamarin Forms 3.0 this still seems to be an issue, specifically IsVisible binding not working for StackLayout and any of its children, on Android when a parenting ScrollView is used. Setting IsEnabled=false/true and Opacity=0/100 via property change was the only thing that worked for me.